# My laptop stuck after trying to install ubuntu

Tags: installation, windows, usb, plymouth

I was trying to install ubuntu from a disk on key to my laptop (did it already on my desk top a few months ago)
i choose to install ubuntu in the options and then i got stuck on a purple background while the mouse cursor was active in that screen. after few minutes that nothing changed i shut down my computer, took out the disk on key and just wanted to run my computer (had windows os)
but nothing worked no more, not even the basic screen of the computer when it restarts, when i put the disk on key back, and restarted the computer it just went stright back to that purple screen.

what can i do to fix it?

Comment: did you start install ? when purple screen come

Comment: i choose that option, but then that screen came and nothing changed since then, didn't look like anything is installing as i had the mouse cursor free to use

Comment: what screen did you see last? GMT Tİme, Username ? or disk creation

Comment: nothing, there was the option screen to choose if i want to install or use ubuntu along with few other options.
i choose install, it prossessed for a few seconds then that purple screen came

Comment: i writed my answer . if it is true please confirm

Answer (score 0):

From Comments , You started parting disk so windows was deleted . you need a new install . if you will get same error , try another version of ubuntu . like 12.04.1 LTS